# What are service workers in ionic2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, service-worker

I noticed the following block in my index.html

```
     <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('assets/service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->
```

and I'm not sure exactly what it is and cannot seem to find much on it.

Comment: Try googling for "service worker". BTW, this has nothing to do with ionic (or angular, or TypeScript for that matter).

Comment: `cannot seem to find much on it` really? https://www.google.nl/search?q=service+worker+ionic2 first result... please try to find the answer yourself instead of immeidately jumping to SO